# What are the MAX and MIN in C? #define function

Tags: c++, c, max, c-preprocessor, min

I am a student and my teacher gave me and exercise already solved for studying, in his exercise I see this line:

```
 #define MIN(a,b) ((a) < (b) ? (a) : (b))
```

I never used the #define before.

I do not understand what:

```
((a) < (b) ? (a) : (b))
```

stands for.

Looks like if '?' was a comparer not sure. Anybody can help me?

Comment: Look up the [ternary operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:)

Comment: That's a macro with a ternary operator in it. Both topics will be covered in any textbook on C.

Comment: Note the use of `(` & `)` around each use of the arguments (the `a and `b` in the macro) in the "expansion" of the macro - what is plugged in as the textual replacement (which is what the preprocessor does with each reference to MIN( a, b ) it finds in the code.  This is to avoid nasty effects when one macro is nested inside another or contains expressions that may be misinterpreted if not wrapped in said `(` and `)` when expanded...!

Answer (score 7):

It's called the conditional operator (or ternary operator)

```
#define MIN(a,b) ((a) < (b) ? (a) : (b))
```

Means:

```
if ((a) < (b)){   
  return a;  
} else {   
  return b; 
}
```

So if you would do:

```
int test = MIN(5,10);
```

test would be 5

Troubles linking to the wiki page: http://goo.gl/bw2sL

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering and well, that was very quick. As I said I am new to this! Really thanks. I never heard of this operator.

Comment: Just a little extra help what would this stand for: "if (!ngames)"? What is the condition? ngames is an integer

Comment: @JoséAlgarra `if(!ngames)` is equivelant to `if(ngames==0)`

Comment: This will go wrog for example with: `MIN(512, genRandomNumber());`
genRandomNumber() is called once during the test (a) < (b) and again when the else-branch is chosen, the second call will yield a different random number, so that you may end up returning a value larger than 512. Bigger picture: the macro fails if one of its arguments is a function call that depends on a global variable. General lesson: don't use the preprocessor to define functions.

Answer (score 3):

`#define` defines a new preprocessor macro, which in this case place's the MIN code at the point where you place it; with the `a` and `b` "variables" being replaced with whatever you gave to the macro as inputs.

```
 #define MIN(a,b) ((a) < (b) ? (a) : (b))

 MIN(5,6);
 //gets expanded to
 ((5) < (6) ? (5) : (6))
```

The actual expression is using the ternary operator to, do return either A or B depending on the evaluation of the expression, you can read more about it here:

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other

Finally, as you marked your question with c++, please consider the non macro max and min functions.

```
#include <algorithm>
...
int i=std::min(5,6);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer I am looking the links really helped.